# Where can I find a database with a list of all magic cards?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I am going to write a program to manage my library of Magic cards and I am looking for a database file or list of all of the cards that have been released.  I know that the Gathering site is useful, but it limits the number of cards I can return in a search.  I would happily accept a spreadsheet file, database file, or even a text file.

The more information contained in the database, the better.  Having associated images would just be fantastic, but at this point I would settle for names and basic stats of the cards.

Comment: Cockatrice just scrubs Gatherer set-by-set when you set it up. Their code to do it should be open-source (you'll want to look at the `oracle` tool).

Comment: Note that technically you'd be breaking Wizard's terms of service if you scrape all the images from Gatherer. I'm sure you don't care about that if it's for personal use only…

Comment: I'm guessing half the fun for you will be building the program, but just in case you didn't know, if you're using Windows, the [Magic the Gathering Online client](http://www.wizards.com/magic/digital/MagicOnline.aspx) can also track collections offline. You might want to check that out because it is possible to [export a csv collection](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ddZhIJmAu0) file.

Comment: And for those who don't take fun in programming their own tool and still need to manage their library, there are also online tools to do so. I'm using [deckbox](http://deckbox.org/) but I assume there are others as well.

Comment: Please see [my comment on the other question](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/13407/magic-card-database-for-websites#comment17603_13407) for why I'm voting to close this one as a duplicate of it.

Comment: I think the other one is the duplicate, considering that it is 3 days old and this one is a year and a half in age.

Comment: @ChristopherRayl, Both questions are identical. Why is one closed as off-topic instead of duplicate? If it's **indeed off-topic**, it's off-topic for both questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can grab a complete list [here](http://webpages.charter.net/jfarnworth/Card%20List.xls) it's in .xls too! I have downloaded a copy but it looks to be someone's personal list and might disappear at any time. I don't have the ability to attach a file yet so download it quick!

If that is not what you want then your best bet would be Cockatrice but be aware of breaking the Gatherer ToS.

Comment: Where are the Gatherer TOS?

Comment: @ikegami http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/content.aspx?x=mtg/gatherer/termsofuse

Answer (score 20):

as an alternative, you can also get the full set of cards in JSON format - including all sets, languages, printings and detailed information - from this website: http://mtgjson.com/

This website also provided information to work with its associated site for serving images, found here: [http://mtgimage.com](http://mtgimage.com/). Unfortunately however, subsequently this website has been shut down by WotC.

this websites appears to be designed specifically for developers, with explanations of what each property in the JSON objects means.

Comment: I was playing with this over the weekend and it works quite well, there are a couple of hiccups to look out for. the "booster" attribute of each set object didn't play well with the library I used (Newtonsoft Json). And contrary to my first implementation, converted mana costs cannot be integers. Thanks unhinged!

Comment: As of march 10th, mtgimage.com was shut down and is no longer offering images for Magic the Gathering cards.

Comment: updated my answer to reflect this. shame it was taken down!

Comment: @Patters, Was it even legal? It doensn't stand a chance against MTG.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://www.slightlymagic.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=1347) is it in XML and ASCII, complete from what I gather.

Comment: Appears to be actively maintained.

Answer (score 1):

For people that are still searching for a program to save you set, put in trade cards and or make a wishlist. I found this awesome site that does exactly that! http://deckbox.org/.
After you have listed all of your cards, you can even see the value of your set.

Comment: I was thinking of building a similar tool to the OP. I want my collection organized by which deck each card is in, with the possibility of proxies. Does Deckbox provide this?

Comment: Sort of. You can put decklists in Deckbox, and see how many of each card is in your inventory. Unfortunately, you cannot 'tag' cards to see in which deck they are, or how many you are using across your decks.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen anyone mention this one. But MTG Studio (http://www.mtgstudio.com/) has what you are looking for. I use it to manage my collection.