# Is there a complete database of Pokémon data?

Tags: pokemon

I'm looking for a database (in whatever format) that contains all official Pokémon data (~PokéDex). A good example is the data [serebii.net](http://serebii.net) has, but the owner of the site doesn't seem to be eager to hand his data over.

Thanks!

Comment: You could certainly write a small script (or find someone who can) to extract the data from online resources automatically. The advantage there is that you can update your data yourself whenever new cards are released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Python project](https://github.com/veekun/pokedex) on GitHub contains a lot of up-to-date Pokémon information (including evolutions and moves etc) from the video games, which may be useful to you in some way.

Comment: Why? Pokemon TCG lke MtG is a card game.

Comment: I agree with @user1873. If [this question](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7321/where-can-i-find-a-database-with-a-list-of-all-magic-cards) is allowed here, then asking for Pokémon data should be allowed as well.

Comment: Sorry had a brain-fart and forgot about the TCG. (I read it as a question about the video games, since no mention is made of the TCG in the question.) I think the data I linked to may still be useful in a broad sense, but I'll edit my answer to remove the comment about it being off-topic.

Comment: Thanks, a csv database with everything was in fact something I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Can't vouch for its completeness, but http://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-trading-card-game/database/ seems to be a similar resource to the Magic TCG's "Gatherer".

Certainly when I made a request for cards with the name "Pikachu" I got 27 card results, so it seems like it could keep a deckbuilder busy for quite a while...

Comment: I was looking for one that I could download and use myself, but thanks for the time :)