# Magic card database for websites

Tags: magic-the-gathering

How is it that websites like SCG or CFB created their card database inventory. How would i be able to do this myself now? I want to create a similar website where a user can search and find any card with images. Obviously entering manually into a sql server is not feasible. Any help on easiest way to get this done?

Comment: How would your site differ from either [Gatherer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/) or [magiccards.info](http://magiccards.info/)?

Comment: @jwodder well it will be store based like the so many other card web stores out there. I am coming with a totally different approach though. Oh course problem is i don't know how to setup the DB.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find a database with a list of all magic cards?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7321/where-can-i-find-a-database-with-a-list-of-all-magic-cards)

Comment: @ghoppe I actually think that question should be closed as a duplicate of _this_ one! The one you linked is just a plea for a current file (an excel, database or even text file) that contains all cards - a file which will expire within months - and it sets a very low bar for what's acceptable. It's a poor canon question. _This one_ however is asking for a way to gather such a database oneself, rather than asking for one, and answers to this will be relevant to users possibly several years into the future. This question is _way_ better.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming and commerce. This site is for asking questions about games, not how to build a website about them.

Comment: While I agree with Jonathan that this is a better question, I also agree with Pow-lan. Even though it's similar to the previous question, it's actually off-topic.

Answer (score 6):

There's a program called Gatherer Extractor which can extract all info and images from Gatherer. You can export it to an XML file which you can import easily into (eg) a MySQL database.

You can check the sets which you want to download, and the info you want.

Link: http://forums.mtgsalvation.com/showthread.php?t=303454

Comment: i wish i had known about this a month ago, i spent hours writing android code to parse a full text spoiler file from atogatog, and its still not finished!

Comment: @Ivo, Is this legal?

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but I am pretty sure [magic.tcgplayer.com](http://magic.tcgplayer.com) offer a crystal commerce solution to the stores selling cards through their platform. This includes a card database which is updated by them (an advantage if you are lazy, can be a disadvantage if you want to take advantage of the pre-order market).

I believe they only offer this to US based stores, so outside of the US you might not be able to make this work for you, inside however its a very easy set up which works well on mobile devices as well as regular browsers, and can be customized quite significantly.

This may not suit your needs personal, but others looking to start a new online magic singles store may well want to go down this route.

Comment: TCG Player has an API which you can use to get card prices. These prices are based on US stores. You can use this outside of the US (I use it from the Netherlands). For this API you have to send a command with the card name and the setname (not mandatory). It's not possible to get a complete list of cards.

Comment: @IvoGeersen that's true, however that is their publicly consumable API, I am talking about the system they hand out to the stores who subscribe to their program, which is different. The original question does not include it, but the asker commented that he was looking to open a card store, this answer may well be useful for him or others in a similar position.

Comment: I have the "closed" API, and I can only look up prices per card (not by bulk). However, it's possible to send a complete deck to the tcgplayer.com shopping cart, but if Mnramos92 wants to open his own store, he should probably build his own database and fill it with the tcgplayer.com prices, but I don't know if they want to give access to someone with his own shop ;)